# Hexadecimal Arithmetic Operations with Jquery Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving numbers in Hex format. I want to do arithmetic operations with these without having to convert them to decimal and back again? It would be something like:

> var a= a23b
>    var b = f65
>   var c = a + b

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible, jQuery doesn't do math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery - Javascript can do this.

If your numbers are hex you can do:

```
var a= 0xa23b;
var b = 0xf65;
var c = a+b;
```

if you need to convert from some string data you can use `parseInt()` first:

```
var a = parseInt('a23b',16);
.
.
```

And finally, if you need to display a hex result convert to a hex string with `.toString`;

```
var aDisplay = a.toString(16);       // Plain hex number
```

or

```
var aDisplay = '0x'+a.toString(16);  // hex number with '0x' prefix
```